# Use of Breakpoint Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, built-in

I am new to python and am unsure of how the breakpoint method works. Does it open the debugger for the IDE or some built-in debugger?

Additionally, I was wondering how that debugger would be able to be operated.

For example, I use Spyder, does that mean that if I use the breakpoint() method, Spyder's debugger will open, through which I could the Debugger dropdown menu, or would some other debugger open?

I would also like to know how this function works in conjunction with the breakpointhook() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, debugger *will not open itself automatically* as a consequence of setting a breakpoint.

So you have first *set a breakpoint (or more of them)*, and then *manually launch a debugger*.

After this, the debugger will perform your code as usually, but *will stop performing instructions when it reaches a breakpoint* - the instruction *at the breakpoint itself it will not perform*. It will pause *just before it*, given you an opportunity to perform some debug tasks, as

- *inspect* variable values,
- *set* variables manually to *other values*,
- *continue* performing instructions *step by step* (i. e. *only the next instruction*),
- *continue* performing instructions *to the next breakpoint*,
- *prematurely* stop debugging your program.

This is the *common scenario for all debuggers of all programming languages (and their IDEs).*

For IDEs, launching a debugger will

- enable or reveal debugging instructions in their menu system,
- show a toolbar for them and will,
- enable hot keys for them.

*Without setting at least one breakpoint, most debuggers perform the whole program without a pause (as launching it without a debugger), so you will have no opportunity to perform any debugging task.*

(Some IDEs have an option to launch a debugger in the *"first instruction, then a pause"* mode, so you *need not set breakpoints in advance* in this case.)

---

Yes, the `breakpoint()` built-in function (introduced in Python 3.7) stops executing your program, enters it in the debugging mode, and you may use Spyder's debugger drop-down menu.

(It isn't a *Spyders' debugger*, only *its drop-down menu*; the used debugger will be still the `pdb`, i. e. the default **P**ython **D**e**B**ugger.)

The connection between the `breakpoint()` built-in function and the `breakpointhook()` function (from the `sys` built-in module) is very straightforward - *the first one directly calls the second one.*

The natural question is *why we need two functions with the exactly same behavior?*

The answer is in the *design* - the `breakpoint()` function may be changed *indirectly*, by changing the behavior of the `breakpointhook()` function.

For example, IDE creators may change the behavior of the `breakpointhook()` function so that it will launch *their own debugger*, not the `pdb` one.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you could also answer the [updated] latter part of the question.

Comment: This answer is about breakpoints in general, but I think the question is actually about the `breakpoint()` builtin from [PEP 553](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/).

Comment: @H.Khan, I probable misunderstood your original question, so after your update I updated my answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of the `breakpoint()` builtin is to open the [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) debugger at that point.

That is, by default the line

```
breakpoint()
```

Should behave identically to

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

The behavior can be customized (e.g. to open a different debugger) by modifying `sys.breakpointhook`. Generally the only time you would do this is if you were implementing a debugger or something that functioned like a debugger. If you're running code from an IDE, the IDE itself should modify `sys.breakpointhook` so that it opens the IDE debugger. (I don't know if all Python IDEs actually do this, but they should.)

For more information, including the rationale of why this function was added, see the [PEP 553 proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/). The actual implementation was landed into Python 3.7.